# Is it possible to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to specify location of system libraries in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, path, libraries

I have a 32-bit application which is developed and runs in Ubuntu 14.04. I tried running the application in Ubuntu12.04 and obviously it failed due to dependency issues. My question is, is it possible to make the application look for *libraries* in some custom location instead of `/usr/lib` or likewise, say, I copy `libstdc++` from 14.04, wrote a script as part of the application telling `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to use this location. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. [That is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`'s purpose...](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

If you have libraries in `/opt/mylibs`, you can use them to start an application by pointing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` there. Typically in your situation you'd do this in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mylibs /opt/myapp/app
```

This will run `/opt/myapp/app` using libraries from `/opt/mylibs`.

Comment: I wrote a script in Ubuntu14.04(to execute an application, say A) which copies libstdc++ from /lib to a folder created by the application and from their to /opt/XYZ .Then I added /opt/XYZ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This script is being called from another application, say B.. Now I am trying to run B from Ubuntu 12.04(All required files and folders are copied to this system). But the application is looking for libstdc++ in the standard location itself.

Comment: You need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in a script which starts A. I'll clarify my answer...

Comment: Yes Thankyou...I haven't specified app path in the command.

Comment: Is it possible to copy `ld-linux.so`  in the same way? I get the following error when trying to execute the application:  `relocation error: /opt/XYZ/deps/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_find_dso_for_object, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux.so.2 with link time reference`

Comment: To use a replacement `ld-linux.so`, you need to run it explicitly; so you'd end up with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/XYZ/deps /opt/XYZ/deps/ld-linux.so.2 /opt/myapp/app`.

Comment: The solution you gave worked in `Ubuntu12.04`. But now the same error is shown in `CetOS6.8`.